# Make grid view with no gaps between elements

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here's my current code:

```dart
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 5,
          childAspectRatio: 1,
        ),
        itemCount: 25,
        itemBuilder: (_, __) => Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the output it gives:

[image: Notice the gaps between some widgets?]

Notice the gaps between some grid items?

I've tried 10 different variations on this, with `Expanded`, with `AspectRatio`, with `SizedBox`, and all approaches seem to yield the same exact result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue about it on github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29702

but you always can make a simple hack:

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 5,
          childAspectRatio: 1,
        ),
        itemCount: 25,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraintes) => OverflowBox(
            maxHeight: constraintes.maxHeight + 0.5,
            maxWidth: constraintes.maxWidth + 0.5,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I'll try this out and see if it works for my use case, and report back. Thanks alot!

Comment: It's sad that we need a workaround for this right now, but it works pretty well, thanks for this :)